# icon not showing in taskbar when windows form minimized

Tags: vb.net, winforms, resources

I have a winforms application on Windows 7 64 bit with Visual Studio 2019
I have created other apps that do not have this issue
**icon not showing in taskbar when windows form minimized**

The main difference with this app is I am using a button on one form to minimize the form
Both project forms are configured the same Control Box = False Maximize = False Form Border = Fixed3D
I am not using ico in the title bar that should be obvious based on the forms configuration.

What I have tried is Project > Project Properties > Resources and add an ico 256 x 256 to the Resources folder that has a png file already added. This png is used in a Picture Box.
That did not fix the issue. Next I tried to go to the Application and add the ico in the appropriate place.
I also deleted the ico from the Resources folder and just added it to the project. No Luck with that.

**The question is what setting am I missing?

OR How do I get the ico to show in the taskbar**

Comment: But, did you set the `Icon` Property of your Form in the designer? Adding an Icon the Project's Resources is not relevant (unless you use it to set the Form's Icon Property at run-time).

Comment: Windows that are normal, a titlebar with a system menu, appear on the taskbar. Windows that want to appear on the taskbar but don't meet the requirements can set an extended window's style of an AppWindow. See sample code https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2021/04/this-uses-inbuilt-compilers-in-windows.html

Comment: @Jimi No I did not set anything in the form ! Will give that a try So just use the Application setting and do NOT place the ico in the Resources folder

Comment: Well, you need to. Just set the `Icon` Property in the Designer, or at run-time set `Me.Icon = My.Resources.SomeIcon` (ideally in the Form's Constructor)

Comment: @Jimi That worked for the form in question GREAT The other forms need the same setting so the ico shows in the taskbar ever if the form is not minimized I am guessing but will give it a try Thanks

Comment: You can always build a base Form and inherit from it all other Forms that require the same *look and feel*.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have "ShowInTaskbar" in the form properties set to True. I had this same issue.